# ValueError: cannot reshape array of size 408 into shape (256,256)

Tags: python, numpy, reshape

I am trying to match the shapes of two ndarrays because of this error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "step2_face_segmentation.py", line 62, in <module>
    prepare_mask(input_path, save_path, mask_path, vis_path)
  File "step2_face_segmentation.py", line 24, in prepare_mask
    face_remain_mask[np.subtract(face_segmask, render_mask) == 1] = 1
ValueError: operands could not be broadcast together with shapes (3,136) (256,256)
```

This is the solution I came to:

```
face_segmask = face_segmask.reshape((256,256))
```

And now I get this error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "step2_face_segmentation.py", line 63, in <module>
    prepare_mask(input_path, save_path, mask_path, vis_path)
  File "step2_face_segmentation.py", line 22, in prepare_mask
    face_segmask = face_segmask.reshape((256,256))
ValueError: cannot reshape array of size 408 into shape (256,256)
```

Where am I going wrong?

This is my function

```
def prepare_mask(input_path, save_path, mask_path, vis_path=None, filter_flag=True, padding_flag=True):
    names = [i for i in os.listdir(input_path) if i.endswith('mat')]
    for i, name in enumerate(names):
        print(i, name.split('.')[0])
        # get input mask
        data = loadmat(os.path.join(input_path, name))
        render_mask = data['face_mask']
        seg_mask = load_mask(os.path.join(mask_path, name))
        face_segmask, hairear_mask, _ = split_segmask(seg_mask)
        face_remain_mask = np.zeros_like(face_segmask)
        np.resize(face_segmask,(2,204))
        face_segmask = face_segmask.reshape((256,256))
        face_remain_mask[(face_segmask - render_mask) == 1] = 1
        stitchmask = np.clip(hairear_mask + face_remain_mask, 0, 1)
        stitchmask = remove_small_area(stitchmask)
        facemask_withouthair = render_mask.copy()
        facemask_withouthair[(render_mask + hairear_mask) == 2] = 0

        if vis_path:
            cv2.imwrite(os.path.join(vis_path, name.split('.mat')[0] + '.png'),
            (data['img'].astype(np.float32) * np.expand_dims(hairear_mask, 2).astype(np.float32)).astype(np.uint8))

        # get triangle
        points_index = np.where(stitchmask == 1)
        points = np.array([[points_index[0][i], points_index[1][i]]
                            for i in range(points_index[0].shape[0])])
        tri = Delaunay(points).simplices.copy()
        if filter_flag :
            # constrain the triangle size
            tri = filter_tri(tri, points)
        if padding_flag:
            # padding the points and triangles to predefined nums 
            points, tri = padding_tri(points.copy(), tri.copy())
        data['input_mask'] = stitchmask
        data['points_tri'] = tri + 1 # start from 1
        data['points_index'] = points
        data['facemask_withouthair'] = facemask_withouthair
        savemat(os.path.join(save_path, name), data, do_compression=True)
```

face_segmask:

```
[[0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0
  0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0
  0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0
  0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0]
 [0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0
  1 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 1 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0
  0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0
  0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0]
 [0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0
  0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0
  0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0
  0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0]]
```

render_mask:

```
[[0. 0. 0. ... 0. 0. 0.]
 [0. 0. 0. ... 0. 0. 0.]
 [0. 0. 0. ... 0. 0. 0.]
 ...
 [0. 0. 0. ... 0. 0. 0.]
 [0. 0. 0. ... 0. 0. 0.]
 [0. 0. 0. ... 0. 0. 0.]]
```

Here is a display of the difference between 2 masks:

```
from scipy.io import loadmat

mask1 = loadmat('/home/onur/Klothed/Deep3dPortrait/examples/0A0LB0L4ZI_scaled.mat')

print(mask1)
print('----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------')
print(mask2)
```

```
{'__header__': b'MATLAB 5.0 MAT-file Platform: posix, Created on: Mon Mar 28 10:51:06 2022', '__version__': '1.0', '__globals__': [], 'id': array([[-1.2797791 , -0.08861017, -0.6052671 ,  0.75098646, -0.22125539,
         0.42110965,  0.03675324,  0.5388979 , -0.27588245,  0.21564549,
        -1.0140698 , -0.4355024 , -0.39568093, -0.20688176, -1.4875108 ,
         1.325931  , -0.84765184,  0.88962275,  0.302525  ,  0.2526361 ,
        -0.5930034 ,  0.07068072,  0.30876353, -1.1546763 ,  0.57377964,
        -0.8415573 , -0.18119523, -0.5464204 , -0.5127071 ,  0.27204332,
        -0.06733536,  0.6742006 , -0.4087138 , -0.7364751 , -0.06032972,
        -0.07004109, -0.27160022,  0.3536133 , -0.00399867,  0.2807463 ,
         0.00761514,  0.25661102,  0.4341182 ,  0.5358836 , -0.04537674,
        -0.85193664,  0.63383555,  0.36327136, -0.33462563,  0.30551806,
        -1.2515804 ,  0.33226335,  1.0087879 , -0.70784366,  0.97863805,
        -0.62455887, -0.07289671, -0.38175532,  0.23046121, -0.2558538 ,
         0.7437248 , -0.11743242, -0.51081884, -0.43395746, -0.9162911 ,
        -0.47645196, -0.1770683 ,  0.4522399 , -0.9090539 , -0.45160767,
         0.27526733, -0.03235929, -0.09474289, -0.39627454, -0.29447377,
         0.64948344, -0.04136639,  0.08102851,  1.167983  ,  0.81159705]],
      dtype=float32), 'exp': array([[-7.37450346e-02,  6.01068791e-03, -6.13361657e-01,
        -6.94821000e-01, -2.62743801e-01, -6.41770720e-01,
         4.07823682e-01,  1.86461642e-01,  2.18004450e-01,
         8.57702911e-01,  1.04152739e-01, -1.91626072e-01,
        -7.24305958e-02, -1.09282982e+00, -8.09790850e-01,
         8.59264135e-01,  8.04834217e-02,  4.86144960e-01,
         8.32746506e-01,  7.74722174e-02, -4.29271795e-02,
         1.31504083e+00,  2.96826750e-01, -1.10164732e-01,
         6.21689141e-01,  1.23533413e-01,  2.88926721e-01,
        -4.31663394e-01,  5.50999865e-02,  2.24491253e-01,
         2.21334726e-01,  3.71961623e-01, -5.27617514e-01,
         5.76893426e-02,  1.27089053e-01, -7.40798414e-02,
         3.53128463e-02,  7.78759941e-02, -3.09281498e-01,
        -1.04859725e-01,  1.87036708e-01,  6.62185401e-02,
        -1.19889423e-01,  5.41671813e-01,  4.53793406e-02,
        -9.49730948e-02, -9.07308087e-02,  1.46967933e-01,
         4.36003655e-02, -2.06840232e-01, -1.25291482e-01,
        -2.96853818e-02,  2.09928025e-04, -2.48879436e-02,
        -2.88952049e-02,  4.82563041e-02,  1.62137635e-02,
         3.81083451e-02,  3.03687295e-03, -7.37828156e-03,
        -1.96418706e-02,  2.04924904e-02,  3.17533538e-02,
        -2.58857734e-03]], dtype=float32), 'tex': array([[-0.44635218, -0.07986047,  0.9534862 ,  2.1112688 , -0.71610826,
        -3.0923328 , -1.6787887 ,  1.4732614 , -0.56091046, -0.6113587 ,
         1.059298  ,  1.0646482 ,  1.2319514 ,  0.7277851 ,  2.8604193 ,
         1.7067136 ,  1.3056533 ,  1.1159464 ,  3.6518831 , -0.41389385,
        -1.3165723 ,  1.1054856 ,  0.5191988 , -0.03465123, -0.27983502,
         1.2240021 , -1.1481704 , -3.8721542 , -0.2844859 , -1.133084  ,
         0.8603149 , -2.276404  , -1.3431422 ,  0.22516142, -2.1005661 ,
        -2.4143603 ,  1.0512475 , -2.1771355 ,  0.3096211 , -0.00673585,
         0.7496163 ,  0.32097048, -0.11727592, -0.55973196,  0.33346167,
        -2.7206528 ,  0.42604917,  1.322218  ,  0.75648916, -2.3558044 ,
        -2.5897725 ,  1.3175619 , -1.8916413 ,  2.763712  ,  1.4556843 ,
        -0.68300265,  0.03587759,  0.15836626, -0.545168  , -0.88595676,
         0.44952008, -0.51778316, -0.4679473 ,  1.8654913 , -1.5340933 ,
        -2.374744  , -0.52612436, -2.2173398 , -0.44482538,  1.2033085 ,
         1.4783537 , -0.5247378 ,  2.1134388 ,  0.11252565, -0.24671124,
         0.7615849 , -3.043861  , -1.9476672 , -0.1799865 , -0.04871672]],
      dtype=float32), 'angle': array([[ 0.1752684 , -0.0613766 , -0.00631663]], dtype=float32), 'gamma': array([[ 0.09903307,  0.05749096,  0.07033499, -0.03441413, -0.00266623,
        -0.08046365,  0.05220436,  0.01396117, -0.01793677,  0.04569122,
         0.05662945,  0.03383157, -0.04022161, -0.01187175, -0.07965071,
         0.10840807,  0.00701178, -0.02354797,  0.02068131,  0.06627281,
         0.01941579, -0.03886013, -0.01103439, -0.07820404,  0.14234464,
         0.00404134, -0.0550525 ]], dtype=float32), 'trans': array([[-0.00402336, -0.00457859,  0.2619188 ]], dtype=float32), 'lm68': array([[[ 44.45605 ,  82.68295 ],
        [ 47.369076, 101.732994],
        [ 51.35461 , 118.30173 ],
        [ 54.743813, 133.21507 ],
        [ 59.24634 , 149.99658 ],
        [ 67.34441 , 164.8591  ],
        [ 77.90727 , 176.53549 ],
        [ 91.92219 , 187.77734 ],
        [112.113144, 194.0116  ],
        [132.89397 , 187.19211 ],
        [148.35362 , 176.33044 ],
        [160.19943 , 164.86969 ],
        [169.40842 , 150.35043 ],
        [174.50703 , 134.00154 ],
        [178.17824 , 119.222305],
        [181.67613 , 102.48628 ],
        [184.41698 ,  83.354324],
        [ 53.72279 ,  70.00293 ],
        [ 60.5366  ,  61.100616],
        [ 70.718   ,  59.203156],
        [ 80.98449 ,  61.178757],
        [ 90.60996 ,  65.267075],
        [129.15652 ,  66.21358 ],
        [138.95303 ,  62.405563],
        [149.62119 ,  59.716843],
        [161.08148 ,  62.12973 ],
        [169.09914 ,  70.46924 ],
        [109.68169 ,  90.27466 ],
        [108.50754 , 103.686424],
        [107.68983 , 115.84379 ],
        [107.83477 , 125.7432  ],
        [ 95.09898 , 131.79193 ],
        [100.73937 , 133.1806  ],
        [108.982376, 134.69888 ],
        [117.24781 , 133.0614  ],
        [123.595   , 131.51582 ],
        [ 67.55201 ,  86.97505 ],
        [ 72.77617 ,  82.87462 ],
        [ 81.680275,  82.39307 ],
        [ 89.72387 ,  86.70874 ],
        [ 82.03709 ,  89.432495],
        [ 73.50433 ,  89.804565],
        [130.88544 ,  86.97542 ],
        [138.95299 ,  82.75925 ],
        [148.14273 ,  83.465836],
        [154.67831 ,  87.340744],
        [147.65247 ,  89.77124 ],
        [138.62311 ,  89.44113 ],
        [ 82.323715, 150.51752 ],
        [ 89.70171 , 147.37425 ],
        [102.00351 , 143.85614 ],
        [109.11615 , 145.30081 ],
        [115.97055 , 144.111   ],
        [129.69475 , 147.25201 ],
        [138.6237  , 151.22894 ],
        [128.95424 , 162.77078 ],
        [119.94918 , 168.69423 ],
        [110.23398 , 169.9521  ],
        [100.43926 , 168.57129 ],
        [ 91.79283 , 162.38539 ],
        [ 85.02247 , 150.91977 ],
        [100.46073 , 151.38914 ],
        [109.27185 , 151.67982 ],
        [118.30343 , 151.88007 ],
        [136.85992 , 151.13521 ],
        [118.62388 , 158.83786 ],
        [109.771576, 159.85703 ],
        [100.80478 , 158.56781 ]]], dtype=float32)}
```

Comment: Because 408 is not divisible by 256*256.

Comment: So how can I solve this?

Comment: But they're still me a mismatch as in the initial error @KevinChoonLiangYew

Comment: Change the array resize to values whose *product* is 408.

Comment: Also @KevinChoonLiangYew `ValueError: cannot reshape array of size 408 into shape (204,204)`

Comment: @S3DEV How can I do that?

Comment: 2 x 204 = 408; 4 x 102 = 408 … see where this is going?  Think about it logically.  You have 408 elements, and those elements must be *evenly* divided among the arrays.

Comment: @S3DEV I am talking about resizing it where the product is 408?

Comment: @KevinChoonLiangYew Just as long as they match

Comment: Check the edits. I've posted the full code..

Comment: @KevinChoonLiangYew So how can I fix it?

Comment: Just one last question before I move on with answer, do you plan to use the 3 * 136 as the fixed matrix and subtract the 256 * 256 matrix accordingly? Also, please remove some of the comments as it's getting too lenghty here

Comment: Not really. I can reshape either. Just as long as they match..

Comment: This is the order of subtraction: `face_segmask - render_mask`

Comment: @KevinChoonLiangYew Check the edits..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You load something from a `.mat` file, and select the 'face_mask' variable.  Without the relevant file we can't examine or recreate that.

```
    data = loadmat(os.path.join(input_path, name))
    render_mask = data['face_mask']
```

then you load something else (`load_mask` is unknown), and run the unknown `split_segmask` function:

```
    seg_mask = load_mask(os.path.join(mask_path, name))
    face_segmask, hairear_mask, _ = split_segmask(seg_mask)
```

According to the error, `face_segmask` is (3,136)

```
    face_remain_mask = np.zeros_like(face_segmask)
```

`resize` does not operate in-place, so this does not change `face_segmask`:

```
    np.resize(face_segmask,(2,204))
```

Then you try to reshape it instead.  Why (2,204) in the resize, and (256,256) here.  `resize` can change the total number of elements; `reshape` can't.  I think you need to reread the function documentation!

```
    face_segmask = face_segmask.reshape((256,256))
```

The error here says `face_segmask` has 408 elements (flatten view of (3,136)).  That's not all the same as 256*256.  `reshape` is NOT a image 'resizer'.

```
    face_remain_mask[(face_segmask - render_mask) == 1] = 1
```

your original error go here, with (3,136) (256,256) shapes. What where you imagining would happen here?  The arrays don't have any dimensions in common.  How's it supposed to do ELEMENT-WISE subtraction.  By subtraction we mean `3 - 4 = -1`, not some sort of set or image "removal".

I'm not sure you understand array shapes, and specifically why your arrays have shapes they have.  And it isn't clear what you trying to do with this subtraction.

I can imagine the (256,256) array representing an image.  But what's the (3,136) array?  How is that supposed to relate to or map on the (256,256) space.  What's the 3 dimension?  3 color channels perhaps?  And the 136?  indices of some sort?

In your other questions you appear to be processing images, trying perhaps to identify features like 'faces' or 'hair'.

Comment: Check the edits. I've posted an example of what the mask looks like..